# Двумерная упаковка - алгоритм

Tags: php

Кто сталкивался с одним из алгоритмов по решению задачи двумерной упаковки? На хабре нашел пару статей. Может, кто-то писал на любом другом языке, чтобы переписать на php?

Comment: Я вот только не понял для каких целей реализовывать подобное в php :)